# cv::Mat::create causes error: (-215:Assertion failed) s >= 0 in function 'setSize'

Tags: objective-c, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to mark the rect of sub image within the provided image. The following code works when I share the image from app bundle. If I pass the image captured from the device openCV framework throwing an error.

`error: (-215:Assertion failed) s >= 0 in function 'setSize'`
at line

**result.create( result_cols, result_rows, CV_32FC1);**

Code :

````
+(UIImage *)featureDetection:(UIImage*)largerImage withImage:(UIImage*)subImage
{
    cv::Mat tempMat1 = [largerImage CVMat];
    cv::Mat tempMat2 = [subImage CVMat];
    
    cv::Mat result;

    int match_method = cv::TM_SQDIFF_NORMED;

    
   // cv::cvtColor(tempMat1, tempMat1, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
  //  cv::cvtColor(tempMat2, tempMat2, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    
    int result_cols =  tempMat1.cols - tempMat2.cols + 1;
     int result_rows = tempMat1.rows - tempMat2.rows + 1;
    
    result.create( result_cols, result_rows, CV_32FC1);

    /// Do the Matching and Normalize
    cv::matchTemplate( tempMat1,tempMat2 ,result,match_method);

    double minVal; double maxVal;
    cv::Point minLoc, maxLoc, matchLoc;
    
    cv::minMaxLoc(result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, cv::Mat() );
    if( match_method == cv::TM_SQDIFF || match_method == cv::TM_SQDIFF_NORMED ) matchLoc = minLoc;
    else matchLoc = maxLoc;

   NSLog(@"%d %d",tempMat1.cols,tempMat1.rows);
   NSLog(@"%f %f",minVal,maxVal);

    if (minVal < 0.25) {

        NSLog(@"success");

        cv::rectangle(tempMat1,matchLoc,cv::Point(matchLoc.x + tempMat2.cols , matchLoc.y + tempMat2.rows),CV_RGB(255,255,255),-1);
                        
        UIImage *resImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCVMat:tempMat1];
        
        return resImage;

       // return YES;
    }
    else {

        NSLog(@"no match");
      // return NO;
    }
    
    return  [[UIImage alloc] initWithCVMat:tempMat1];
    
}```
````

Comment: either result_cols or result_rows is negative. you can figure out why your code makes them negative, and you should catch that situation and throw your own error.

Comment: oh, matchTemplate will resize the output matrix anyway (if it doesn't have the right size), so don't bother doing that explicitly... it should anyway, that's an implied expectation of many OpenCV APIs.